# Тест Ферма (проверка на простоту)

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа

Функция проверки числа на простоту по малой теореме Ферма:

```
import math
import random

def is_prime(num, test_count):
    for i in range(test_count):

        rnd = random.randint(1, num - 1)

        if (rnd ** (num - 1) % num != 1):
            return False

    return True

print(is_prime(13, 10))
```

Сказано, что надо выполнять большее кол-во тестов, чтобы результат был точнее (чтобы с меньшей вероятностью наткнуться на "обманщиков" Ферма").

---

В книге Рода Стивенсона "Алгоритмы" сказано: "..для натурального числа p минимум половина значений n между 1 и p - свидетели Ферма... Вам может не повезти, и вы возьмете в качестве n обманщика Ферма...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

***Сам вопрос:*** я проводил тесты и никак не находил этих "обманщиков" Ферма... Кроме, собственно числа **1**. Как "наткнуться" на *это* число, или я что-то неправильно понял/делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понимаете, вам сказали, что свидетелей никак не меньше 50%. Это - **оценка снизу**, т.е. если обманщики и есть, то их **не больше** 50%. Например, 0.0001%. Или вообще нет - это тоже менее 50% :) Кстати, оценка 50% у меня вызывает определенные сомнения - есть, например, числа Кармайкла, где это значение, насколько мне помнится, куда большее...

Простейшие обманщики - 4, 11, 14 для числа 15. 3 штуки, примерно 20%. Следующие обманщики есть только для 21, для всех промежуточных их нет.

Для 91 = 7 * 13 их 35, более 38%.

Так что обманщики есть, просто вам не повезло на них наткнуться.

Сами посмотрите на p = 561 или 1105, сколько обманщиков там.

P.S. Я в Питоне не силен, как в нем с диапазоном целочисленных значений? а то одно дело 10 в 12 степень возвести, и совсем другое - 300 в 500... Вы бы на всякий случай цикл сделали, да в цикле возведение в степень по модулю просчитывали.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение) ночью читал про псевдопростые числа и понял всё. Да,  я не обратил внимание на именно "оценку снизу".

Comment: Да,  в книге как раз и предлагали реализовать возведение в степень по модулю, но я алгоритм писал только с точки зрения обучения,  а не практического применения)